# Mirror modifier without seam

Tags: modifiers, mirror

I'm using mirror modifier with merge and clipping enabled to create a very low poly model. Generally - every single triangle counts. I'm also a newbie, so this question might be stuipid.

Is there a way to use mirror modifier so that it DOESN'T create new vertexes at the point my model and mirrored parts merge? I know they are needed in most cases, but in my it's just extra work to remove them.

Comment: The merge option means that vertices at the centre don't get duplicated, only the vertices away from the merge line get duplicated across. Do you mean your getting faces through the mirrored line? An image or two may help clarify.

Comment: AFAIK, no. The best you can do is delete the edge loop after applying the modifier. You could try the [*Snap to symmetry*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Basics/Mirror#Snap_to_Symmetry) tool, but it's a lot less convenient than using the mirror modifier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you mean by seam an edge loop like the one selected in this image (along the y-axis).

[image]

Once you have applied the mirror modifier you could:

- Select the edge loop <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>RMB</kbd>
- Delete edge loop <kbd>X</kbd>

I wouldn't recommend to apply the modifier since you couldn't apply symetrical changes as easy as before. IMHO it's not worth to sacrifice editability for saving a few faces.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, deleting all the edge loops produced is pain, but it seems that there isn't any other way. And sadly, thanks to some weirdnes in performance, removing edge loops gives me a very decent boost to performance.

Comment: @madziorek15 I thought you only want to remove the edge loop along y-axis, removing more of them would decompose your geometry. Game engines render millions of triangles, so you shouldn't be worried about a few faces.

Comment: Well, not this one sadly, it's streaming content through net and sadly it all counts. To give you impression - removing all edge loops gave me about 6 times less cost to stream it.

Comment: @madziorek15 what do you mean 'all' the edge loops? It's just 1 single loop around the middle.

Comment: if you have a joint mesh yes, but my model is in quite a lot of parts

Comment: @madziorek15 In that case, my idea for you is: Select those "border" vertices BEFORE applying the Mirror modifier. After applying, Tab into Edit Mode, you'll see that all the vertices are already selected. :) Just keep that selection unchanged, then simply X > Edge Loop (or Dissolve Edges) to delete them all. Tip for quick selection on border: **Ctrl Shift Alt M** when in Vertex / Edge Select mode. (Suppose the openings of your model are where will be merged by Mirror Modifier)

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem it took a while but I figured it out, my mesh seemed to split in the middle when I applied a multires modifier.  I found that when I turned off the mirror modifier for some reason when I had done an edge loop cut and slide it had added faces to the loop edge that was my clipping so when ever I was applying the mirror it was confused because the edge loop it was supposed to merge had faces.  Turn off the mirror and if the side you want to merge has faces delete them and all will be good. (Tthe side you want to merge is the side you can't see when the mirror mod is on.)

Comment: I don't understand what you are writing here. Please use shorter sentences and try to be clearer.