# small gap while drawing

Tags: modeling

i am trying to follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDJkIu8xvk4&t=655s tutorial to draw basic lime. but there is small gap in center of the lime which you can see [image: here]. it is very frustrating, what is the worng with me although i follow tutorial carefully?

thanks,

Comment: do you have a Mirror modifier? if not, perhaps use W > Remove Doubles so that the vertices stick

Comment: no, i dont use miror, in tutorial he is starting drawing from center one side and againg from center to other side.

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5861" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5861/)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5458/mirror-modifier-without-seam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said you have vertices overlaying, so select all and press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*, it will merge these vertices. Also, you need to recalculate the normals because some are flipped, so select all and press <kbd>ctr</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

[image]